# Cursor Position is incorrect when CSS Transform Matrix property is applied to container

Tags: ace-editor

I'm using Ace Editor in my App and when CSS Transform Matrix is applied to the container div, the cursor position is positioned incorrectly. when I start typing, it types at a different place than where the cursor is.
But when the zoom is brought back to normal, the cursor is positioned correctly.

I searched for this issue and most of the solutions are related to setting monospaced font and not setting letter spacing to 0. I checked both of them and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ace doesn't check for zoom when calculating mouse position, since it is a non-standard css property.
As a workaround you can set zoom on the ace container to `1/global_zoom`, and increase the font size instead.